# iOS8でWKWebViewのユーザエージェントを変更するには

Tags: objective-c, ios8

WkWebviewでユーザエージェントを変更したいのですが、iOS8の場合変更する方法が分からず悩んでおります。
ご存知の方がいれば、ご教授願います。

```
MainController.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) WKWebView *webView;

MainController.m
@synthesize webView = _webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
// 初期化
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
_webView.navigationDelegate = self;
_webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true;
[[self view] addSubview:_webView];

// ユーザエージェント設定
[_webView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id __nullable userAgent, NSError * __nullable error) {

    NSString *myUserAgent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ AppName", userAgent];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0) {
        _webView.customUserAgent = myUserAgent;
    } else {
        // ユーザエージェントが変わらない(_webView.customUserAgentはiOS9から）
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"UserAgent": myUserAgent}];
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。 AppDelegateのdidFinishLaunchingWithOptionsで[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"UserAgent": myUserAgent}];を実行したところユーザエージェントが変更されました。